# What's the smartest way to select specific table elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a table with hidden rows on it, like such

```
 -visible-
 -invisible-
 -visible-
 -invisible-
```

When I click on a table row, I want it to show the invisible row. Currently I have that using this function:

```
var grid = $('#BillabilityResults');
$(".tbl tr:has(td)").click(
         function () {
             $(grid.rows[$(this).index()+1]).toggle();
         }
```

However, this table also hides the visible rows if I click on one of the (now visible) hidden rows.
I'd like the click function to only work on the specific visible rows. Currently all my invisible rows have the class "even" so I figured I could limit the click based on that. However, I can't seem to find the syntax to explain that to my function. How would I go about doing that? And, more importantly, is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to give your visible rows a class and select them based on that

Comment: Why not use show() instead of toggle()?

Comment: @ganeshk I assume, because he wants to be able to hide it as well?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to me, can you clarify it more ?

Comment: MrOBrian, what is the syntax for selecting based on class? I tried ".odd tr:has(td)" and ".tbl .odd tr" and ".odd tr" and ".odd", but none have worked. The odd class is appended to the visible rows. I just don't know how to tell my computer that :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use next:

```
$(".tbl tr:has(td)").click(
  function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  } 
);
```

And also if you have specific selector for odd or even:

```
$(".tbl tr.odd").click(
  function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
  } 
);
```

But I think that the major help with my answer is to use next() that get you the next row, instead of the index process that you were doing.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, and my function looks nicer!

Answer (score 1):

```
var grid = $('#BillabilityResults');
$(".tbl tr:visible").click(
         function () {
             $(this).next('tr').toggle();
});
```

Comment: The (this).next was very helpful, but I'm thinking having the tr:visible would allow the new visible rows to hide the original next visible ones. Thanks for the input!

Comment: it will only bind to the original visible rows unless you are rebinding the function at some point after the new ones are shown

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess Javascript predetermines all the clickable attributes on the page load rather than when you are clicking? I've got a lot to learn still :P

Comment: whenever that code is executed. so if you execute it on page load, then yup it will only attach to the current visible elements

Answer (score 1):

Use the NOT function to disregard the EVEN tr elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/7AHmh/

```
<table class="tbl">
<tr><td>one</td></tr>
<tr class="even" style="display:none"><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>three</td></tr>
<tr class="even" style="display:none"><td>four</td></tr>
</table>​

$(".tbl tr:has(td)").not("tr.even").click(function() {

    alert("Click triggered.");

    $(this).next("tr").show(); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could check for even/odd rows with the modulus operator before calling your toggling code:

```
function() { // your anonymous function
    if (rowNumber % 2 == 0) { // only even rows get through here
        // toggle code here
    }
}
```

I hope it helps.